# Keep session alive in remote site using CURL and php

Tags: php, curl

My code is doing the login to a remote site using CURL. But it is not keeping the session alive there. In my case I am logging into the site using the following code.

```
        $username=$options['session[login]']; 
        $password=$decryptedPassword; 
        $cookie = tempnam("/tmp", "cookies");  

        $postdata = "session[login]=".$username."&session[password]=".$password; 

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
        $result = str_replace("href=\"","href=\"$onappurl\\",$result);
        $result = str_replace("href=\"$onappurl\\","href=\"$onappurl",$result);
        echo $result;
        curl_close($ch);
```

Now the result is echoed in a popup and it is showing logged in interface. But if I click on any link of the site, I loose the session and it is redirected to the login page.

Comment: Are you looking for using your server as a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because your server is sending the request, and the remote site is creating a session for your server, not for you. So, if you click a link that redirects to that remote site, and you do not have an active session there, you will be prompted to log in.

Comment: so how can I get rid of this and setting an active session in server, is that possible..? If I do a header redirect after login , then it will work ?

Comment: Do you have any control of the remote site?

Comment: It is also installed in our sever. But I would like to keep it intact if there is any other methods for doing it.

Comment: Then I dont have a solution, Im sorry

Comment: If I can make changes, then how we can do it ? I am having an onapp installation.

Comment: You could pass a session token along every request, in the URL. Then, according to that token, pull the appropriate details from the session.

Comment: just fixed by myself. Using CURL, fetched the wole HTML and then submitted the form using JS with username and password. Working fine now.